# Stuck at initiallizing COM out-of-process object in C#

Tags: c#, com, out-of-process

I need to embed a out-of-prcess COM execution in my C# application. The COM execution is written in C++/ATL. 
Sometimes my COM create process will not start, so I manage to use a timeout to interrupt it.

My COM object initializing process:

```
using MyCOM;
//...
private MyCOM.Mylib _com;  // COM object
private void MyInitJob()
{
    _com = new MyCOM.Mylib();            
}
private bool Initial()
{
    System.Threading.Thread mythread = new System.Threading.Thread(MyInitJob);
    mythread.Start();
    if (!mythread.Join(5000))
    {
        mythread.Abort();
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The above code seems could not stop `MyInitJob()` thread while timeout is reached, and `Initial()` will hang forever when new a COM object is stuck.

Could I know why `new` takes forever, and could I interrupt when it takes too long?

Comment: What is the threading model of the COM object? Maybe you need a `[STAThread]`?

Comment: This code is just a band-aid, it cannot stop the bleeding.  Thread.Abort() can only actually abort a thread when it is busy executing safe code.  C++ code is not safe, the Abort() call will just hang.  Nor is there anything reasonable you can do next but terminate the program.  You need to debug the C++ code.  Enable unmanaged debugging or start VS again and attach to the unmanaged server process.

Comment: The COM object is a third-party execution working "as it", seems hard to debug this execution.